# Resizing plot graph from R in Emacs automatically for Ubuntu 13.04 Bug

Tags: r, ubuntu, graphics, emacs

In Ubuntu 13.04, when plotting using R, it will now not automatically display. I am aware this is a bug, but I am looking for a temporary solution.

Does anyone have an Emacs or R solution how to automatically resize the plot window or something on a plot call? It is really annoying to resize the window constantly.
My best solution now is to use `C-S-left`, which sticks the window to the left edge, automatically resizing.

Comment: What is your question?  Many of us have used R via ESS for a decade+, include many years on Ubuntu. But "will not automatically display" is not something I can make sense of.  I plot from ESS all the time, where the windows goes is a function of the _window manager_ and yes, there are programmable one and no, I don't use one.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't think you're running the latest Ubuntu version (13.04), since the bug only occurs there. The issue is that whenever you plot, you need to reshape the window in order for things to be drawn on the plot.

Comment: This is as far as I have seen bugs go: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-latest-Ubuntu-release-13-04-disables-R-graphics-device-td4666582.html

Comment: But it seems like an issue with the graphics -- I am running these very Ubuntu builds on a number of machines at home and work and can assure you that there is no systemic issue.  And for what it is worth I am also running a mix of 12.10 and 13.04 across different machines.  To make this more concrete: what is your graphics card?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Well thanks for confirming that this is then a problem on my side. It packs the NVIDIA NVS 3100M, and indeed, it can't run the optimized part of the graphics card on Ubuntu I believe. This is really sad though. Dirk, do you use RStudio or Emacs?

Comment: ESS/Emacs all the time, RStudio a little.  I use NVidia at home (and the Nvidia drive makes me mad for another reason) and I will re-try there this eve.  My laptop with its Intel 4000 graphics has no problems whatsoever...

Comment: I can plot without any issues on my desktop with Ubuntu 13.04, R 3.0.1 and a proprietary NVidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

the problem of no graphics in R after updating to Ubuntu 13.04  is solved by upgrading R to 3.0.0 This might cause some other issues with outdated packages, but it solved the problem in my machine. see http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2013/03/moving-to-r-300-on-ubuntu.html